# Transforming a list of triples in a peculiar way

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list of triples:

```
list = {{3, 1, 2}, {4, 8, 9}, {6, 5, 7}}
```

I want to trasform `list` into

> ```
> {3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}
> ```

This is my current method:

```
last = Last /@ list;   
Catenate[
  MapIndexed[
    If[Last[#2] > 1, Function[l, Append[last[[;; Last[#2] - 1]], l]] /@ #, #] &, 
    list]]
```

> `{3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}`

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 8):

For fun,

```
☺ = ## & @@@ {##} &[#, (♯  {## & @@ #[[-1]], ♯}) /@ #2] &;
```

[image]

```
☺☺ = ☺[☺[#, #2], #3] & @@ # &;
☺☺ @ list
```

> {3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}

And, seriously,

```
Fold[Join[#, Function[{x}, {##& @@ #[[-1]], x}] /@ #2] &, list]
Join @@ FoldList[Function[{x}, {##& @@ #[[-1]], x}] /@ #2 &, list]
```

both give

> {3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}

Alternatively,

```
Quiet[Fold[Join[#, Thread[Append[#[[-1]], #2]]] &, list]]/. Append->List
```

> {3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}

Also, with `Nest`:

```
Join @@ Nest[{Join[#, Thread[{Sequence @@ Last @ #, First @ #2}]], Rest @ #2} & @@ # &, 
 {First @ #, Rest @ #}, Length @ # - 1] & @ list
```

> {3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}

Comment: Thanks for nice work..What's meaning of your `ClearAll[foo]` here？

Comment: @yode, my pleasure. Nice question.

Comment: @yode , `foo` is leftover from previous edits. Cleared now.

Comment: @kglr i think you still need `Quiet` for version 9. Just tested and it churns out the same warning message (as in version 10+) without it.

Comment: @Ali, i am using version 9.0 (windows 10) and not getting any message. Maybe it is OS-dependent?

Comment: @kglr strange because i am using windows 10 and version 9.0 myself. +1 nevertheless ! i still need to decipher the one that you call `fun` :p

Comment: @kglr  as a neophyte who may be at risk of wearing out his welcome, shouldn't both Appends in the "Alternatively" section be  ...Append[[3]] ...  ?

Comment: @Rabbit, thank you for drawing my attention to the error.  Changed `#[[1]]` to `#[[-1]]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Module[{mo, le},

 le = Range[Length @ list - 1];
 mo = Take[Most @ list[[All, -1]], #] & /@ le;

 Flatten[#, 1]&@
  Join[
   {First @ list}, 
   Thread[{Sequence @@ mo[[#]], list[[# + 1]]}] & /@ le]]
```

> {3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}

Answer (score 2):

```
f = Join[First[#], Catenate[Table[Append[#[[;; i - 1, -1]], j],
                                   {i, 2, Length[#]}, {j, #[[i]]}]]] &;
f[list]
```

> {3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}

Answer (score 0):

```
f[u_, v_] := Flatten[{Last@u, #}] & /@ v
Catenate@FoldList[f[#1, #2] &, list]
```

yields:

```
{3, 1, 2, {2, 4}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {2, 9, 6}, {2, 9, 5}, {2, 9, 7}}
```